# How to stop Biome giving me the same error message multiple times

Tags: biomejs

[image]

The same error shows ~10 times, how to stop the same error displaying multiple times?

Answer (score -1):

Just disable the rule, theres documentation available:
https://biomejs.dev/linter/#disable-a-lint-rule

Comment: I just want to stop the same error message appearing 10+ times. I defo want to keep all my rules in place :D